# How to get values from multi select with restlet

Tags: java, html, forms, restlet-2.0

I have some html forms which have select inputs that can have multiple values selected. When I post them to my Restlet service I only the currently selected value.  I know that if this were a plain servlet I could use request.getParameterValues(... to get to the array of selected values, but I can't seem to find the equivalent in Restlet.  From what I can tell the service maps the request to a JsonRepresentation but I don't see an equivalent method for accessing the parameter values.

Does anyone know a way to do this with Restlet2.x?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, it depends on the way you post the form from the client. Your question lets me think that you use URL encoded form (`Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`).

In this case, you can extract the submitted data using the class `Form` of Restlet, as described below:

```
public class MyServerResource extends ServerResource {
    @Post
    public void handleForm(Form myForm) {
        // Equivalent from request#getParameterValues for Servlet
        String[] values = myForm.getValuesArray("mykey");
        (...)
    }
}
```

If you want to get a query parameter, simply use the method `getQuery` to get the associated form object:

```
public class MyServerResource extends ServerResource {
    @Post
    public void handleForm(Form myForm) {
        // Equivalent from request#getParameterValues for Servlet
        String[] values = getQuery().getValuesArray("mykey");
        (...)
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry